# Send an Email with an Excel attachment using Marklogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-10

I would like to construct body of an email with excel as an attachment using MarkLogic and JavaScript. Excel should be generated from json response of rest API.
I have been through docs but I could find sample for image attachment.
Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: It's not clear what you question is. Are you saying that you aren't sure how to adapt the examples demonstrating how to attach an image to an email and instead attach an Excel document?

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen thanks for replay!! I would like to attach excel file as an attachment

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen I am able to send an email with an CSV attachment

Comment: var contentType = "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary;

var att1 = xdmp.base64Encode(CSVData());

var part1 = "This is a sample message";
var part2 = {
             "Content-Type": "csv/text",
             "Content-Disposition":"attachment",
             "filename":"Notification.csv",
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding":"base64",
             "attachment":att1
            };